# Calling Meteor methods in React components

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

Currently I'm working on a project based on Meteor as back end and React as front end. I really enjoyed simplicity untill I removed `insecure` package and have to deal with Meteor methods. Right now I need to perform a basic insert operation and I'm just stucked!
I have a form as component (in case eventually I'd like to use this form not only for inserting items but for editing those items as well) and here's my code for this form:

```
AddItemForm = React.createClass({
propTypes: {
    submitAction: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
 },
getDefaultProps() {
    return {
        submitButtonLabel: "Add Item"
    };
},
render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <form onSubmit={this.submitAction} className="col s12">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s6">
                        <input  
                            id="name"
                            placeholder="What" 
                            type="text" 
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field col s6">
                        <input 
                            placeholder="Amount" 
                            id="amount" 
                            type="text" 
                         />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s12">
                        <textarea 
                            placeholder="Description" 
                            id="description"
                            className="materialize-textarea">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row center">
                        <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">{this.props.submitButtonLabel}</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This chunk of code is used as a form component, I have a prop `submitAction` which I use in let's say add view:

```
AddItem = React.createClass({
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const 
        name = $('#name').val(),
        amount = $('#amount').val(),
        description = $('#description').val();
        Items.insert(
            {
                name: name,
                range: range,
                description: description,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                ownerId: Meteor.userId()
            },
            function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("error");
                } else {
                    FlowRouter.go('items');
                };
            }
        );
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <h1 className="center">Add Item</h1>
                    <AddItemForm
                        submitButtonLabel="Add Event"
                        submitAction={this.handleSubmit}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

As you can see I directly grab values by IDs then perform `insert` operation which works absolutely correct, I can even get this data displayed.
So now I have to remove `insecure` package and rebuild the whole operation stack using `methods`, where I actually stucked.
As I understand all I should do is to grab same data and after that perform `Meteor.call`, but I don't know how to pass this data correctly into current method call. I tried considering this data right in the method's body which doesn't work (I used the same `const` set as in `AddItem` view). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this method knows something about where I took the data (or may be I don't really get Meteor's method workflow), so by this moment I ended up with this code as my insert method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    addItem() {
        Items.insert({
            name: name,
            amount: amount,
            description: description,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            ownerId: Meteor.userId()
        });
    }
});
```

and this is how I changed my `handleSubmit` function:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const 
        name = $('#name').val(),
        amount = $('#amount').val(),
        description = $('#description').val();
    Meteor.call('addItem');
},
```

Also I tried declaring method like this:

```
'addItem': function() {
    Items.insert({
        // same code
    });
}
```

but it also didn't work for me.
Again, as I understand the problem isn't about data itself, as I wrote before it works just right with `insecure` package, the problem is how the heck should I get this data on the server first and right after that pass this to the client using methods (also console gives no even warnings and right after I submit the form, the page reloads)? 
I've already seen some tutorials and articles in the web and didn't find desicion, hope to get help here.

Comment: Did you subscribe to the collection? I don't really know if you need to be subscribed to push to a collection but it might be a possibility.

Comment: Also I think your going to need to pass those properties you set to the Method call itself. Meteor.call('method') does not know what the name, amount, description ... vars are unless you pass them in the call Ex: Meteor.call('method', name). Yeah that's probably why no data is inserting.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
Yes, I subscribed to my collection, I made this in List component through pub/sub.
Well, I tried to pass those vars explicitly to callback, but it doesn't work, because in this case the method doesn't know where to take vars from just like me. I think it's the only issue I have with methods. Without them everything works like excepted, so I probably need a hint about this stuff, a big one :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your data as parameters in your Meteor call function. You can also add a callback function to check on the success of the call.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const 
    name = $('#name').val(),
    amount = $('#amount').val(),
    description = $('#description').val();
  Meteor.call('addItem', name, amount, description, function(err, res) {
    if (err){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err,null,2))
    }else{
      console.log(res, "success!")     
    }
  });
},
```

In your Meteor methods:

```
Meteor.methods({
  addItem(name, amount, description) {

    var Added =  Items.insert({
      name: name,
      amount: amount,
      description: description,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      ownerId: Meteor.userId()
    });

    return Added

  }
});
```

Comment: If I ever have a son, definitely I'm gonna name him Mark. In other words, thank you sir, it worked smoothly.